# Queuing strategy for Flex AMF Remoting requests to a Java server

Tags: java, apache-flex, queue, blazeds

The Flex Remoting service to a Java server need to do a synchronized task. I need to queue the AMF requests while one is currently in progress and once it's done then execute others in FIFO order. I thought of JMS but the use-case does not require a subscriber/publisher pattern. A simple synchronous queue would suffice. Kindly suggest design & implementation strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite if I understood..why not executing the second request when the result event of the first one is triggered? And so on for the other ones?

Comment: This is when the same client is requesting. I'm asking for a scenario when multiple clients request for the same resource at the server.